# Changing the value in a tuple of tuples conditionally in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, element

I'm working on 3-tuples of 3-tuples `((a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i))`. Now I want to take this tuple as input and as output generate a list of tuples in which an element is changed to a value if it had a certain value.

Example:

`changefromtovalue :: a -> a -> ((a,a,a),(a,a,a),(a,a,a)) -> [((a,a,a),(a,a,a),(a,a,a))]`

`changefromtovalue 1 5 ((0,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,3,4)) results in [((0,5,2),(1,2,3),(2,3,4)),((0,1,2)(5,2,3)(2,3,4))]`

Now i'm not using integers, but the idea stays the same i think.

First I thought I wanted some kind of map, but that would change all values at once, instead of making a list with 1 element changed each.

Then I thought, I can just make all variations (in the example `[((5,x,x)..),((x,5,x)..),((x,x,5)..)]` and somehow drop the ones that don't meet the requirements, but I can't figure out a clean way to drop the unwanted ones.

I've tried searching and found some information about making a data specification for the tuple, but I fail to see how that would really simplify this particular problem.

Converting to a list and working with the list and then converting back seemed easier, but it still requires a weird kind of selection. If possible I'd like to avoid using a lot of conversions.

What I'm looking for is a suggestion that leads to a clean way, not a full cut-out line of code.

Comment: What do you need this cumbersome type for? Do the task allow to replace it with something more convenient?

Comment: Yes it does, but I fail to see how converting `((a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i))` to `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]` or `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]` would make this particular task easier.

Answer (score 2):

With the additional information you provided in a comment, we can solve this using Richard Bird's approach:

We instead represent the grid as a list of lists. We then replace each element in the grid with a list of the choices we can make for it. In your example, `1` becomes `[1,5]` (we either choose a 1 or a 5) and `n` becomes `[n]` (for everything else, there are no alternative choices).

```
choice                :: Int -> [Int]
choice 1              =  [1,5]
choice n              =  [n]
```

Then we make this choice for each element:

```
choices               :: [[Int]] -> [[[Int]]]
choices               =  map (map choice)
```

Now comes the tricky part. We reduce a grid of choices to a choice of grids, which can be done using the general cartesian product of a list:

```
cp                    :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cp []                 =  [[]]
cp (xs:xss)           =  [y:ys | y <- xs, ys <- cp xss]
```

We collapse a grid of choices like so:

```
collapse              :: [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]
collapse              =  cp . map cp
```

This works by first collapsing a list of rows of choices (a.k.a a grid of choices) into list of choices of rows and then collapsing the list of choices of rows into a choice of lists of rows, a.k.a, a choice of grids.

Finally, we specify a solver by first making the choices and then collapsing them:

```
solve                 :: [[Int]] -> [[[Int]]]
solve                 =  collapse . choices
```

For example:

```
> mapM_ print (solve [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])

[[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
[[0,1,2],[5,2,3],[2,3,4]]
[[0,5,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
[[0,5,2],[5,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

Hopefully this also demonstrates how converting the tuples to a list of lists makes this task easier.

---

Note: Some of you may have noticed that `cp` is `sequence` for the list applicative. This means we can also equivalently write:

```
solve' = sequence . map sequence . choices
```

Comment: That would probably work and reading through your solution I've found my own solution. For those interested, I'll write it in an answer.

Comment: `solve'` can also be written `traverse (traverse choice)`, skipping `choices` altogether while simultaneously generalizing the type to allow each table to be represented by, e.g., a vector of vectors, or even a vector of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

With tuples you have to write:

```
change x y ((a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i))
     = ((z a, z b, z c), (z d, z e, z f), (z g, z h, z i))
  where z w = if w == x then y else w
```

Life would be easier if you used a list (or an array) to represent your 3x3 grid.

Comment: This changes all x into y and gives me a new tuple, I want to change individual x and each changed tuple to be added to a list.